# How to enable autoescaping in Twig using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using Twig in my Symfony project.

Symfony should enable [autoescape by default](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#output-escaping). However it doesn't do this by default and after I enable it by hand it still won't work.

I've configured Twig to autoescape all my variables.

```
twig:
    autoescape:   true
```

But this doesn't filter anything. Both HTML and JavaScript aren't escaped.
There is no custom autoescape_service and I'm not filtering the variables with `|raw` or `{ autoescape false }`.

I've double check the generated config to make sure the value hasn't been overwritten.
In *app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml* under the twig service definition the arguments are as follows:

```
<argument key="debug">true</argument>
<argument key="strict_variables">false</argument>
<argument key="cache">false</argument>
<argument key="autoescape">true</argument>
<argument key="exception_controller">twig.controller.exception:showAction</argument>
<argument key="autoescape_service">null</argument>
<argument key="autoescape_service_method">null</argument>
<argument key="charset">UTF-8</argument>
```

Is there another way that Twig overwrites the autoescape option that I'm missing? Or how can I force enable it?

Comment: What do you ouput? Template variables? Twig extension functions?

Comment: Template variables, entities are passed to the view and often the properties are printed. like {{ message.content }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find the problem after asking my questions after wasting hours trying to find a solution.

During development twig.autoescape was set to false.
Later XSS protection was needed. And and {{ autoescape }} block was added to some of the fields. Some time later a `|raw` filter has been added in the autoescape block to disable autoescaping on some fields again.

I missed the `|raw` filters in the unnecessary autoescape blocks. (I must have skipped the content thinking autoescape was set to true, but the `|raw` filter gets applied later so the content stays raw.